# Exiting due to DRV_CREATE_TIMEOUT: Failed to start host: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, minikube, minishift

When I run `minikube start --driver=virtualbox --host-only-cidr='192.168.59.1/24'` I get the following output

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox --host-only-cidr='192.168.59.1/24'
  minikube v1.24.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Using the virtualbox driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ..
  Deleting "minikube" in virtualbox ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ..
  Failed to start virtualbox VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

❌ Exiting due to DRV_CREATE_TIMEOUT: Failed to start host: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  Suggestion: Try 'minikube delete', and disable any conflicting VPN or firewall software
  Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7072
```

I'm not certain why this is not working. Any idea?